# Empty User-Agent causes sql exception column "os" violates not-null constraint

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

Having WSO2AM (API Manager) 2.1.0 with an Analytics server (on PostgreSQL) we see following issue:

if a client call an API with no *User-Agent* header, the analytics server is unable to complete processing and in the logs of the analytics server (wso2carbon.log) there are following exceptions:

```
TID: [-1] [] [2017-10-10 10:55:17,292] ERROR {org.apache.spark.executor.Executor} -  Exception in task 0.0 in stage 41522.0 (TID 32785) {org.apache.spark.executor.Executor}
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO API_REQ_USER_BROW_SUMMARY (api, version, apiPublisher, tenantDomain, total_request_count, year, month, day, requestTime, os, browser) VALUES ('agenda.brussels', '0.0.2', 'admin', 'carbon.super', 1, 2017, 10, 10, 1507625491000, NULL, NULL) ON CONFLICT (api,version,apiPublisher,year,month,day,os,browser,tenantDomain) DO UPDATE SET total_request_count=EXCLUDED.total_request_count, requestTime=EXCLUDED.requestTime was aborted: ERROR: null value in column "os" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (agenda.brussels, 0.0.2, admin, carbon.super, 1, 2017, 10, 10, 1507625491000, null, null).  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.BatchResultHandler.handleError(BatchResultHandler.java:145)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2156)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:460)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeBatch(PgStatement.java:793)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeBatch(PgPreparedStatement.java:1659)
...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "os" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (agenda.brussels, 0.0.2, admin, carbon.super, 1, 2017, 10, 10, 1507625491000, null, null).
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2455)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2155)
        ... 16 more
```

Apparently the "os" field is assumed as not empty. The APIs and clients are  public, so we have no way to enforce the request sent from the clients.

I'd see temporary measures

- set some User-Agent value if empty in the http proxy level (I am not sure if we are allowed to)
- is it feasible to update the processing script to use coalesce postgresql function? (returning some default value of null argument is used).

Questions:

- is it a bug (known/unknown) or we missed something? If so, what would be the best way to resolve it?

Thank all for any hint

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: @neuhaus indeed, the question is updated: is it a bug (known/unknown) or we missed something? If so, what would be the best way to resolve it?

Comment: already answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45734329/wso2am-analytics-2-1-null-value-in-column-os-violates-not-null-constraint/46719903#46719903